# sql statement conditions

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I want to select all the Female patients from the patient table where the area = south or area= west and then group the result by Disease name 
So I had to write the where condition like this :

```
command10.CommandText = "SELECT D.DiseaseName, COUNT(D.Patient_ID) AS PNO FROM PatientAffectDisease D INNER JOIN patient P on D.Patient_ID = P.Patient_ID WHERE P.Gender='" & "female" & "'" & " AND P.Area='" & "south" & " '" & "OR P.Area='" & "west" & " '" & " GROUP BY DiseaseName "
```

But this doesn't return the right result.

Any Idea?

Comment: is case sensitivity turned on in your DB?  if so, you may need to handle everything as Upper or lower to get the desired matches (which will really suck when you want indexes to be used)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put parenthesis around your OR'd conditions

e.g.

WHERE P.Gender='" & "female" & "'" & " AND 
(P.Area='" & "south" & " '" & "OR P.Area='" & "west" & " '" & ")

or just use an IN clause ...
where p.gender = 'female' and p.area in ('south', 'west')

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you had extra spaces after south and west with this code:  `" '"`

You were trying to find 'south ' or 'west ', not 'south' or 'west'.

You can also modify this condition to use an IN clause.

```
command10.CommandText = "SELECT D.DiseaseName, COUNT(1) AS PNO FROM PatientAffectDisease D INNER JOIN patient P on D.Patient_ID = P.Patient_ID WHERE P.Gender='female' AND P.Area IN ('south', 'west') GROUP BY DiseaseName"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your where clause specifically related to not using parentheses.

```
command10.CommandText = 
"SELECT D.DiseaseName, COUNT(D.Patient_ID) AS PNO " & _
" FROM PatientAffectDisease D " & _
" INNER JOIN patient P on D.Patient_ID = P.Patient_ID " & _
" WHERE P.Gender='female' AND P.Area in ('south','west') " _
" GROUP BY DiseaseName "
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your posted query isn't working properly is because you have an extra space after 'west' and 'south' in the generated query.

You should always group your logic with `()` to make it easier to maintain and understand the code - and keep away from bugs such as this one.

`AND` binds harder than `OR`, so what you had earlier was the same as writing:

```
(P.Gender = 'female' AND P.Area = 'west') OR P.Area = 'south' -- not correct
```

---

Instead of using `P.Area = 'west' OR P.Area = 'south'` you can use the `IN` operator, as in the below example:

```
SELECT     D.DiseaseName, COUNT(D.Patient_ID) AS PNO 
FROM       PatientAffectDisease D
INNER JOIN patient P ON D.Patient_ID = P.Patient_ID
WHERE      P.Gender = 'female' AND P.Area IN ('west','south')
GROUP   BY D.DiseaseName
```

---

```
command10.CommandText = "SELECT D.DiseaseName, COUNT(D.Patient_ID) AS PNO FROM PatientAffectDisease D INNER JOIN patient P ON D.Patient_ID = P.Patient_ID WHERE P.Gender = 'female' AND P.Area IN ('west','south') GROUP BY D.DiseaseName"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the text of your query:

```
SELECT 
   D.DiseaseName, 
   COUNT(D.Patient_ID) AS PNO 
FROM PatientAffectDisease D 
    INNER JOIN patient P on D.Patient_ID = P.Patient_ID 
WHERE P.Gender='female' 
     AND P.Area='south ' 
     OR P.Area='west '
GROUP BY DiseaseName
```

In SQL, the `AND` naturally [has precendence over](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx) the `OR`.

So you're effectively asking

```
 WHERE (P.Gender='female' AND P.Area='south') OR (p.Area = 'west' )
```

You must use brackets to explicitly state the precedence you need

```
 WHERE P.Gender='female' AND (P.Area='south' OR p.Area='west')
```

Comment: @Lion are you saying that my posts are badly formatted? :O ;)

Comment: @refp:) No that doesn't mean at all. I have just vote up all the answers too.